# Unused CPU resource from a reserved resource allocation in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

Does OpenShift 3.x ever allocate unused CPU resources that are reserved for containers?

*To illustrate my question, imagine the following scenario. I have a dual-core (2000 millicore) node; I have two pods running on this box, each with a reservation of 1000 millicore and a limit of 2000 millicore. Pod A is very CPU intensive during the day, Pod B is very CPU intensive at night. Is Pod A ever able to burst up to its limit (or a proportion of it) and into the Pod B's 1000 millicore allocation when the Pod B is not using its resource allocation? Would OpenShift keep the reserved resource unused and therefore wasted if the pod that had reserved the resource was not using it in full?*

*My understanding is that while the reservation is a guaranteed amount of CPU resource that a pod can use, it would be strange if the node would intentionally throttle other pods while keeping that CPU allocation idle. I cannot see in the documentation whether OpenShift does consider unused reserved CPU resource allocation to be "excess CPU" or not*

I do know that the above illustration is a very poorly configured OpenShift node but I have simplified the debate I was having earlier today for this query to explain it!

Comment: Behaviour is described under 'Quality of Service Tiers' in the documentation. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#quality-of-service-tiers

Comment: That was one of the documents I read. I should have clarified, I am referring to the following:

*A Burstable CPU container is guaranteed to get the minimum amount of CPU requested, but it may or may not get additional CPU time. Excess CPU resources are distributed based on the amount requested across all containers on the node.*

Does a CPU reservation on other containers that is not being fully utilised, come under "excess CPU resources"?

Comment: If an application has ``request`` and ``limit`` the same it falls within 'Guaranteed CPU'. Either way, the scheduler will only deploy pods on nodes where it is guaranteed that CPU amount specified by ``request`` isn't allocated based on sum of other ``request`` values. If that application is idle, other applications falling within 'Burstable CPU' or 'BestEffort' CPU can use it, but, if the application with 'Guaranteed CPU' needs it, it takes precedence and will get it, with others being throttled.

Comment: The key bit is that ``request`` values control where the scheduler places pods. This is so that a node is not overloaded. That said, things get a bit more complicated if the cluster has been set up to run in mode called 'overcommit'.

Comment: Thanks Graham. The bit *If that application is idle, other applications falling within 'Burstable CPU' or 'BestEffort' CPU can use it, but, if the application with 'Guaranteed CPU' needs it, it takes precedence and will get it, with others being throttled* is exactly what I needed! :)